# Getting Error when download the source through Tortoise workbench?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Am  getting error to download the source code from TortoisHG Workbench . I had apply  for "Do Not Verify the host Certificate" and I added the  below line for Mercurial.ini  file for hostfingerprints  .

```
[hostfingerprints]
hsisc1 = a0:52:39:6d:f8:d8:b2:c5:3f:00:74:ed:c5:de:de:f3:71:04:68:d0
```

but still now am getting same error . please help to resolve this issue.

find to attached the screen shot also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same error (show it) as before, it can be due

- Wrong fingerprint in `[hostfingerprints]`
- Using another name, than `hsisc1`, on pull|push commands (or in repository's .hgrc)